# How do I get the copyright info from the Bing daily wallpaper JSON?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I have a powershell script that grabs the Bing daily image, and saves it on my pc as "bing.bmp":

```
irm "bing.com$((irm "bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&mkt=en-IN&n=1").images[1].url)" -OutFile bing.bmp
```

And that works fine. I would also like to pull the **image description** from the same file it is pulling the url from. The value is called "copyright", and I can't seem to get it. I tried this:

```
irm "bing.com$((irm "bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&mkt=en-IN&n=1").images[1].copyright)" -OutFile bing.txt
```

but it didn't work. Is there any way I can get the value "copyright" from the JSON file, and output it as a .txt file?

EDIT: This is the JSON I am trying to pull the value from:

https://bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&mkt=en-IN&n=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, first query the API to get the details for today's wallpaper and store that response in a variable for future use. Then you could use the **Title** from the JSON object to create a new folder where you can save the wallpaper as well as the Copyright details.

```
$json = Invoke-RestMethod "bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=js&mkt=en-IN&n=1"
$title = $json.images.Title
$folder = New-Item "Today's Title - $title" -ItemType Container
$copyrightfile = Join-Path $folder -ChildPath "Copyright.txt"
$wallpaperfile = Join-Path $folder -ChildPath "$title.bmp"
$json.images.CopyRight | Out-File $copyrightfile
Invoke-RestMethod "bing.com$($json.images.url)" -OutFile $wallpaperfile
```

One thing to note, `(...).images[1].url` should be just `(...).images.url` from what I could see.

Comment: my pleasure @ClaytonTDM :)